# How can I automate a large number of dropdowns without having to make webelement of each one separately

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been asked to automate a website all of a sudden at my company and I am stuck on the part where I have to automate 5-6 dropdowns one after other

The code with 5-6 webelements for every dropdown doesnt seem right

```
Json File::
         {
         "username": yawningemu3,
         "password": any,
         "cpassword": any,
         "email": vishek3242@gmail.com,
         "cemail": vishek3242@gmail.com,
         "gender": Man,
         "country": India,
         "ethnicity": Indian
         }
```

I cant seem to find a way to optimize the given part of the code:

```
      package com.thinksys.pof;

      import java.io.FileReader;
      import java.util.List;

      import org.openqa.selenium.By;
      import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
      import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
      import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
      import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
      import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
      import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

      import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
      import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

       public class Registration 
      {
     public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException
       {
        {
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

     try 
     {

   Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("..//POF//data.json"));

   JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) obj;


   String username = (String) jsonObject.get("username").getAsString();
   String password = (String) jsonObject.get("password").getAsString();
   String cpassword = (String) jsonObject.get("cpassword").getAsString();
   String email = (String) jsonObject.get("email").getAsString();
   String cemail = (String) jsonObject.get("cemail").getAsString();
   String gender = (String) jsonObject.get("gender").getAsString();
   String country = (String) jsonObject.get("country").getAsString();
   String ethnicity = (String) jsonObject.get("ethnicity").getAsString();


    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","..//POF//geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.pof.com/");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60, 50);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*
          [@id='wrapper']/div[1]/div/div/span[1]/a"))).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='blue-box-fluid-
     round']/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input[3]")).sendKeys(username);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='blue-box-fluid-
      round']/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(password);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='blue-box-fluid-
      round']/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(cpassword);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='blue-box-fluid-
     round']/center/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(email);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='blue-box-fluid-
       round']/center/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(cemail);

    WebElement gen = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='blue-box-fluid-
        round']/center/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/select"));

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    Select index = new Select(gen);

    index.selectByVisibleText(gender);

    WebElement month = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='blue-box-
          fluid-round']/center/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/select[1]"));

    Select index1 = new Select(month);

    index1.selectByVisibleText("September");

    WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='blue-box-fluid-
    round']/center/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/select[2]"));

    Select index2 = new Select(date);

    index2.selectByVisibleText("15");

     WebElement year = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='blue-box-
      fluid-round']/center/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/select[3]"));

     Select index3 = new Select(year);

     index3.selectByVisibleText("1995");

     WebElement ethn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='blue-box-
       fluid-round']/center/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/select"));

     Select index4 = new Select(ethn);

     index4.selectByVisibleText(ethnicity);

     WebElement coun = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='country']"));

     Select index5 = new Select(coun);

     index5.selectByVisibleText(country);
      }


        catch (Exception e) 
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }
     }
```

Pardon me for any silly mistakes, I am still new to this.
I am thinking about making a function but cant seem to come to a good strategy

Comment: please paster the html code snippet

Comment: can you share you page html code, so that we can help you bettter?

Answer (score 0):

Few things.

1. Don't use long xpaths until there is no way to identify element. use name or id. This code would break even if small change happen in Table html.
2. it is always a good idea to have separate WebElement rather than having array to element and then accessing them. So what you are doing is good, just use better identifier.

However, if you are just interested in knowing how you could do this, following is the code.

```
List<WebElement> dropdowns = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='blue-box-fluid-round']/center/table/tbody/tr//select"));
new Select(dropdowns.get(0)).selectByVisibleText(gender);
new Select(dropdowns.get(1)).selectByVisibleText("September");
```